# Sharepoint web part dynamic number of controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts

### Background

I'm designing a autocomplete search web part to add to an existing site. Here's the concept:

I need there to be a checkbox on the web part for each of a list of entity types. The list of entity types is pulled from a database. These checkboxes will define what entities the web part will search for.

### Example

So, for example, I might have teachers, students, schools, and classes as my list of entities. The user should see a checkbox for each one of those. Alternately, I might only have teachers and classes as the types. In that case the user should only see those two checkboxes.

So if I knew how many checkboxes I needed ahead of time, I could do this:

```
[WebBrowsable(true)]
[WebDescription("Teachers")]
[WebDisplayName("Teachers")]
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
public bool SearchByTeachers { get; set; }

[WebBrowsable(true)]
[WebDescription("Classes")]
[WebDisplayName("Classes")]
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
public bool SearchByClasses { get; set; }
```

But obviously I can't do that since I don't know how many I'll need.

---

### TL;DR

I don't need any help with the implementation, **I just want to know how I can have a dynamic number of controls on the web part, since they're driven by the properties of the web part class.**

Comment: First, I haven't done sharepoint development in about four years, so I'm trying to think back through about 15 dev projects. We had a similar problem and it seems the solution we ended up with was to use a Flags Enum property in the webpart whichwas set by a webpart connection to a second webpart that presented the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint WebParts are just ASP.NET controls.

You can add controls dynamically through the `Controls` collection. There is nothing preventing you from making a database connection/read an xml configuration file/etc to get the source for your controls.

Example:

```
this.Controls.Add(new Checkbox() { Text = "Hit me"});
```

Comment: but then how would I control the persistence and configuration and stuff?

Comment: Put whatever you need to configure the web part in the database, then in the `CreateChildControls()` method, add the controls that you need, based on what is in the database. You can store a key to the `<connectionStrings>` element in your webpart properties, to get the connection string that is in your web.config.

Comment: How would I get the checkboxes to show up when the user clicks "edit web part", though? Isn't that solely determined by the properties of the web part class?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have clarified a little better. these checkboxes need to be visible in edit mode, not manifest themselves to the end user

Comment: you can use `if (WebPartManager.DisplayMode == System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.EditDisplayMode)

{
// Do something
}` - then storing per user configuration info in a table to persist it

Comment: that's just going to add the controls to the regular view, but only when the editor is open. I'm talking about getting it to display in the actual editor box for the web part